# In C#, which one is faster — Convert.ToString(), (string)casting or .ToString()?

Tags: c#, string, casting, converters, tostring

In C#, which one is faster?

- System.Convert.ToString(objThatIsAString)
- (string)objThatIsAString
- objThatIsAString.ToString()

Comment: I think that the speed differences would be so low that it's not worth worrying about at all, chances are Convert.ToString just does a cast internally.

Comment: @Nathan - but with the extra overhead of the method call. In general operations will be faster than methods, but I totally agree this is micro-optimisation.

Comment: @annakata of course, but yeah it's a sure case of micro-optimization.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The direct cast doesn't have to do any checking except a runtime type check - I would *expect* that the cast is quicker.

You might also want to consider `objThatIsString.ToString()`; since (for `string`) this is just `return this;`, it should be quick - certainly quicker than the `Convert.ToString`. Then the race is between a runtime type-check and a virtual call; in reality, both are very, very quick.

Comment: Your expectations match with the test results below!

Answer (score 22):

@thijs:
Here's a quick test:

```
public class ToStringTest
{
    private object mString = "hello world!";
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    private List<long> ConvertToStringTimes = new List<long>();
    private List<long> ToStringTimes = new List<long>();
    private List<long> CastToStringTimes = new List<long>();

    public ToStringTest()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            sw.Start();
            ConvertToString();
            sw.Stop();
            ConvertToStringTimes.Add(sw.ElapsedTicks);
            sw.Reset();

            sw.Start();
            ToString();
            sw.Stop();
            ToStringTimes.Add(sw.ElapsedTicks);
            sw.Reset();

            sw.Start();
            CastToString();
            sw.Stop();
            CastToStringTimes.Add(sw.ElapsedTicks);
            sw.Reset();    
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Average elapsed ticks after converting {0} strings",ConvertToStringTimes.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("ConvertToString: {0} ticks", ConvertToStringTimes.Average() );
        Console.WriteLine("ToString: {0} ticks", ToStringTimes.Average());
        Console.WriteLine("CastToString: {0} ticks",  CastToStringTimes.Average());
    }

    private string ConvertToString()
    {
        return Convert.ToString(mString);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return mString.ToString();
    }

    public string CastToString()
    {
        return (string) mString;
    }
}
```

Results in:

Average elapsed ticks after converting 100000 strings

ConvertToString: 611.97372 ticks

ToString: 586.51461 ticks

CastToString: 582.25266 ticks

Comment: Finally an answer without any "shoulds" or "woulds" in it :) Good job.

Comment: Nice - a definite +1; I don't know when the question became a wiki - that seems unfortunate; IMO you're due some points.

Answer (score 6):

The cast is faster.

The `Convert.ToString` will eventually do a cast after some overhead. It actually does it in the form of attempting to cast it to `IConvertible`, and then call the virtual method `ToString` on it. So, it's the virtual call that does the actual casting to `String`.

Answer (score 3):

The cast `(string)obj` should be faster. The Convert class actually converts objects that are of different class and will be slower in this case.

Answer (score 1):

There's a saying "The numbers tell the tale". Which means that instead of assuming something you can also measure it!

So, wrap up a test app, run your tests and validate the results!

The true question could be: 
How do I measure which way is faster?

Answer (score 0):

I think that `(string) objThatIsString` is faster because the Compiler will be able to do this conversion at compile time.

However, Jeff Atwood thinks that its not important after all ([Coding Horror: The Sad Tragedy of Micro-Optimization Theater](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001218.html))

Comment: The compiler will only step in if the *variable* is known to be string; otherwise, it'll emit a runtime type check.